# How to include multiple Xcode projects in a master project

Tags: xcode

I recently asked about [the wisdom of using multiple Xcode projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929087/dividing-a-project-into-multiple-xcode-project-files) to separate project components.  I have decided to follow this route in my next project.

I attempted to add another project to a master Xcode project by dragging and dropping it into the sidebar.  However, when I #import any of the classes that are defined in the added project I am informed that those classes cannot be found.

What do I need to do in order to be able to refer to the classes in other projects in a master project?  I was surprised that I found virtually no information on how to do this on the web.

Comment: Since this question was asked, Xcode began supporting [workspaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/creating_a_workspace.html) which should be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Project -> Edit Project Settings`

Use Header Search Paths

This is a list of paths to folders to be searched by the compiler for included or imported user header files (those headers listed in quotes) when `compiling C, Objective-C, C++, or Objective-C++`. Paths are delimited by whitespace, so any paths with spaces in them need to be properly quoted. See the description of the `Always Search User Paths` build setting for more details on how this setting is used. If the compiler doesn't support the concept of user headers, then the search paths are prepended to the any existing header search paths defined in `Header Search Paths. [USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS, -iquote]`

Comment: After adjusting the header search path, all import statements no longer complain, but the linker still gives error like this `  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MagicalRecordHelpers", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o` Any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: yes, you also need to add the target of the project you're adding as a library that you link with