# how to have multiple projects acts like one app

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing a big application (developed as separate projects ) that actually need to be linked in one project and access them via a menu.
is that possible?

What I have done so far is :

1) I have made a project which will contain the main navigation menu. (Let's call it Master).

2) I have imported the desired projects A, B into Master.

although I was able to access class files of A and B from Master. But I could not make it pushed the desired view `viewController` in the project `A` it says `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'ViewController *' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'`

I am stuck at this point. so, any advice on having multiple projects running seamlessly?

**UPDATE** 
I tried to use workspaces I created a test project then included projects A, B.
What I thought was making a button in the test project that pushes the first ViewController of Project A... that would make sense, right? 
but Xcode gives me a red error regarding not found file.

Comment: checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982204/how-to-include-multiple-xcode-projects-in-a-master-project?rq=1, but could not figure it out.

Comment: whats happening to you seems that you have to #import the your view controller in that class,
Are you using any @classViewController in your code?

Comment: which code do you mean the code of project A, or B, or the newest project which will handle them .. ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Workspace concept of Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html)

Comment: i am having a problem regarding accessing controllers inside the sub project, that's what i need to know ..