# Not able to give unique build location in Xcode workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcode-workspace

I am having 2 projects(ProjectA & ProjectB) in workspace. I need to access a file from ProjectA into ProjectB. To make sure that ProjectB is aware of ProjectA files I need to share a common build location

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include multiple Xcode projects in a master project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982204/how-to-include-multiple-xcode-projects-in-a-master-project)

Comment: Its explained for library but I need inputs on direct project

Comment: What sort of file is it?

Comment: Its Objective-C file. I have a file named Test.h & Test.m in project A. I am using it in project B. I had given the header path of Test file  in Target of Project B.  Now I am getting error as "
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Test2", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Sounds like it should me moved to a static library used by the two other projects.

Comment: I want to use it as a separate project instead of library.