# How to do Revision Control for Project Files?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, revision, projects-and-solutions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging Xcode project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022362/merging-xcode-project-files)

I've been using Mercurial for my revision control needs with a small team working on a side project and we seem to be running into a lot of problems dealing with the merging of project files, Xcode project files in this case.

Is there some accepted wisdom for handling these types of merges? Is there a specific merge tool we should be using? What do others do that have larger teams working on Xcode projects? Any advice / help would be appreciated.